# Issue in displaying products : «holes» in my list

Tags: position

I experience an irritating issue with my products «display» on frontend. 
It's not rare that I see «holes» in my products lists pages.

I've placed all my products in correct position in «manage categories» but I still have those white places instead of showing the proper product.

For instance : you'll see in the two next screenshots that there's obviously a displaying problem.

[image: In line 5 there are two «white holes» instead of two products]

[image: What it should look like]

What I did is that I've tried to identify the problematic position : seems to be the 13 on this page. I've then put the product on line 333 (the last line of the list obviously). Problem solved...

Ok, that's good for this one, but  1) I'd like to show this product up in the list and not at the end of the page
2) I encounter this problem in many of my pages.

I use Magento ver. 1.9.2.4
Display settings are the following
[image: Display settings]

And products' positions are here
[image: Products positions]

Could you help me solving this problem or at least giving me a direction to look for... I feel lonely here ! :)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It might be due to some condition in the list.phtml file

Comment: Thank you for answering,  Could you precise please ?